# shifting existing sorce code to ros

Tags: c++, ubuntu, camera, network, nodes

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have not used ROS before and have gone through beginner tutorials on ROS. I want to create two nodes: one on the robot's processor and one on a remote computer connected on the same network. In SSH, I am not able to see the camera feed from the robot, and Remote Desktop lags. So I need a balance between the two situations wherein I can rely on the fast SSH for sending commands and ROS for publishing camera feed.

I have my source code that I want to shift to ROS not entirely but just the part where I am able to publish the camera feed. After going through the wiki I yet didn't figure out how am I supposed to go about it. eg. Should I create a catkin workspace with roscpp etc. and shift the existing folder to src. Then use $catkin_make for compiling files with ROS headers included and $make for compiling the rest of the repository.

The source code is in C++ and both the Robot's processor and the remote computer work on Ubuntu 14.04.2

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218962/shifting-existing-sorce-code-to-ros/) by [arttp2](https://answers.ros.org/users/24037/arttp2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2015-10-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check first if the camera you are using works with any existing ROS nodes that work with cameras. If one does then you will just need to install that on the robot (along with a ROS base install).  Then you will not need to write code to get a camera feed working, just run that node on the robot that already works with the camera, and image view or rviz on the desktop will be able to display the image (with roscore running on one of the machines and correct configuration of environment variables).

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2015-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2